# I need to get the replicate values from a merged cell using Openpyxl. How can I do that?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I always need to get the merged cell as the number of columns it is merged.

This what I have done for Name(merged cell):

```
i=1
j=1
for item in range(0,max_row):
        for item in max_row["A2":"D2"]:
                for x in item:
                        new_sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value = x.value
                        i=i+1
```

This is the source:
[image]

This is what I'm getting from my code:
[image]

This is what I need:
[image]

Comment: You can just check the type of the cell.

Answer (score 2):

## Transform current code

### Useless line #1

The `for item in range(0,max_row):` line does nothing useful as in the next line `for item in max_row["A2":"D2"]:` we rewrite value of the `item`, so let's remove it.

### Useless line #2

There's only one element in the `max_row["A2":"D2"]` so let's just use `max_row["A2":"D2"][0]` and therefore remove the `for x in item:` line.

We got:

```py
i=1
j=1
for x in max_row["A2":"D2"][0]:
    new_sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value = x.value
    i=i+1
```

### And clean it up a bit

```py
i = 1
j = 1
for cell in max_row["A2":"D2"][0]:
    new_sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value = cell.value
    i += 1
```

## Logic

First of all we want to get the string in the title of our merged cell `title = max_row["A1"]`
(it's in the first "subcell" of the merged cell)
Then assign it to one column and the values to the next one:

```py
title = max_row["A1"]

j = 1
i = 1
for cell in max_row["A2":"D2"][0]:
    new_sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value = title.value
    new_sheet.cell(row=i, column=j+1).value = cell.value
    i += 1
```

And from this

[image]

We got this

[image]

## Update

```py
from openpyxl.cell.cell import MergedCell

...

def move_data(title_row, output_row=1, output_column=1):
    start_ind = None
    end_ind = None
    previous_cell = None

    for i, cell in enumerate(max_row[title_row]):
        if type(cell) != MergedCell:
            if type(previous_cell) == MergedCell or start_ind == i:
                end_ind = i
                break
        else:
            assert previous_cell is not None
            if previous_cell.value is not None:
                start_ind = i

        previous_cell = cell

    if start_ind is None:
        for i, cell in enumerate(max_row[title_row]):
            if cell.value is not None:
                start_ind = end_ind = i + 1
                break

    if start_ind is None:
        print("Not found")
        return
    else:
        if end_ind is None:
            end_ind = i

    start_ind -= output_row - 1
    end_ind -= output_row - 1

    title = max_row.cell(row=title_row, column=start_ind)

    j = output_column
    for i in range(start_ind, end_ind + 1):
        cell = max_row.cell(row=j + 1, column=i)
        i += 1 - start_ind

        new_sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value = title.value
        new_sheet.cell(row=i, column=j + 1).value = cell.value
```

This code can handle

[image]

like this:

```py
for i in range(5):
    i *= 2
    i += 1
    move_data(i, output_column=i)
```

[image]

Comment: @Rafael if this answer helped you or you like it, please do not forget to [vote up and mark the answer as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your solution, however I do not know when will appear a merged cell. It is a summarize data. So, merged cell will appear sometimes in ["A1"], sometimes ["BB50"]. It is random.

Comment: @RafaelFernandes It's not a big deal, just iterate through those cells, and if the cell's `.value` is not `None` then it's the start of the merged cell

Comment: and while the cell's type if `MergedCell` then it's still the body of the merged cell

Comment: the structure is like that: "empty cell", "empty cell" ... "cell with the value", "merged cell" ... "merged cell", "empty cell"

Comment: @RafaelFernandes I updated the answer, hopefully now it can be accepted?

Comment: This looks unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @CharlieClark that's for handling of all those cases, but yeah, there are some features that were not requested

Comment: @RafaelFernandes did I answer your question? Could you please [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)?